# California land cases to the US Supreme Court

Tags: united-states, law, california, treaties, land

After the Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo, in the early 1850s, the U.S. Congress created a land commission to [review claims of land ownership](http://www.foundsf.org/index.php?title=Mexican_Land_Claims%E2%80%94The_U.S._Land_Commission_and_The_Burden_of_Proof,_1851-1854) predating California's accession. Hundreds of claims were filed. Many denials were appealed to the federal courts. One such case was *[Meader v. Norton](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/78/442/case.html)*, decided in the Supreme Court in 1870.

How many California land cases were eventually decided by the U.S. Supreme Court?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of them.  I know that's kind of vague but:

> ...In these five years, 813 cases involving private land claims were
> heard by the Commission : 604 claim were confirmed; 190 rejected; and
> the rest were withdrawn. Of these 813 cases, only three were decided
> by the Board: the rest were appealed to the District court and then ***a
> majority of these were finally decided by the Supreme Court***.
>
> [Grants_of_Land_in_California_Made_by_Spanish_or_Mexican_Authorities_State_Lands_Commission.pdf](http://www.californiacentralvalleysurveyors.org/chapter_library/library/Grants_of_Land_in_California_Made_by_Spanish_or_Mexican_Authorities_State_Lands_Commission.pdf)

So if we take this (lengthy) document at face value, over 400 (most) were settled at the Supreme Court level.

Comment: Until someone counts out the land cases in the Supreme Court's own records, this will do.